# The VC dimension of a mixture of normal laws

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, vc-dimension

In his *Statistical Learning Theory* (1998), Vapnik presents the following mixture of two normal laws (p.236), in which the parameters $a$ and $\sigma$ are unknown:

$$p(z;a;\sigma)=\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{N}(a,\sigma)+\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{N}(0,1),\hspace{10mm} a\in(-\infty,\infty), \sigma\in(0,\infty)$$

Since his emphasis in is on demonstrating the Structural Minimisation Principle, Vapnik simply states in passing that the VC dimension of this mixture is *finite*.

I have been working from the definition of capacity for real-valued functions to convince myself that there exists a set of vectors (here, points) $\boldsymbol{z}$ which the complete set of indicator functions over $a$ and $\sigma$ cannot shatter. However, intuition is failing and I can't see a way forward.

I would be grateful for any help, whether through direct reasoning or reference to an applicable general result.

Comment: Developing intuition - views appreciated:  Pick five points, $z_1, z_2, ..., z_5$. There would appear to be no indicator function $\theta$ such that $\theta(z_1)=1, \theta(z_2)=0, \theta(z_3)=1,\theta(z_4)=0,\theta(z_5)=1$. If this bears up rigorously, it points to VC dimension $h\le4<\infty$.

Comment: My reasoning here is that the distribution defines two "hillocks" (Normal distribution peaks). Since the indicator functions are defined based on these, if we consider $\theta(z_i)$ for $i=1, 2...$, we can see, at most, two changes of value from $0$ to $1$ and two from $1$ to $0$. (There can be arbitrarily many consecutive $1$s and/or consecutive $0$s.)